# Efficient way to detect outlier peaks in periodic signal

Tags: dataset, outliers, cross-correlation, signal-processing

I have a set of traces (1D array), and i need to align them, the problem is that, using generic methods ( cross-correlation, dynamic time wrap), would be very slow to align 1 million trace, each with 10 million point,so one of the usual ways of doing that is to use synchronization methods on periodic bases, (once every 10k point for example), and the result is like this:
[image]

So i need to detect when each trace, shift from the rest of traces(or a reference trace), i've already tried correlation and DTW, both too slow, is there any efficient algorithm that can tell when a trace is not aligned with other traces?

Each trace represent a side channel power trace, and those peaks that i need to detect are countermeasures against side channel attacks, like executing some random calculation that have nothing to do with the encryption process.

Edit 1:
I forgot to precise that shifts occurs multiple times in random places, which means that calculating correlation on the beginning of each trace wont align all traces, since every trace will deviate multiple times from the rest of traces.

Until know i used cross-correlation once every 5000 point, the results aren't quiet good , the main issue is that on the data set shifts are completely random, for example from sample 0 to 50k no shifts, and 100 shifts in samples from 50k to 52k.

Answer (score 1):

A very standard approach would be to go [multi-scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_space_implementation), proceeding from coarse to fine. This is different than doing a hi-resolution analysis over windows, because the [coarse signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(image_processing)) are low-pass filtered and down-sampled, i.e. the data is smaller and small peaks are smoothed. The alignment can be done using whatever method (e.g. [DTW](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=multiscale+dynamic+time+warping), [optical flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow)). The idea is that once a coarse alignment has been determined, fine-scale alignments can be constrained to search only a smaller window (i.e. sub-pixel relative to the coarse scale, or nearest-neighbor at worst).

Another common approach would be [feature-based alignment](https://www.google.com/#q=feature+based+alignment). Here you extract keypoints (e.g. peaks) and feature descriptors (e.g. peak geometry, or simply a window around each peak) for each series first, and then align only the features (which could be done e.g. via DTW using an inter-descriptor distance metric). This is commonly combined with a multi-scale approach (e.g. using [SIFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) features).

Answer (score 0):

Your describing a 10m * 1m * float ~ 20GB dataset, is that correct?

Do you have prior knowledge on the possible shift? If the shift is never larger than 10k, you'd need to compute only 10k correlations per series.

1. Compute the correlation on only a sample of the points. Looking at the sample series, it seems the pattern is pretty clear and just a few points should be enough.
2. How are you computing the correlation? If you rewrite the problem as a matrix multiplication, surely it's doable.

For example, reshape each series to 10k rows of 100k columns, where each row is then 10k samples, spaced 10k apart, starting at the index corresponding to the row. Then normalize over the rows.

A reference matrix for a series can be just 10k identical rows of 100k columns, also normalized over the rows.

If you expect your series to be seasonal, it's better to take a different spacing, not one that coincides with the seasonality.

If you then compute this matrix times the reference matrix, you have calculated sample covariances for 10k different alignments.

Comment: reshaping could work, i knew where the misalignment would happen, the goal is to avoid using correlation or dynamic wrap on all samples, since these two methods will tell exactly if a shift happend at some place, i need something less precise, but really fast